# Is there a Javamail Store with an SQL backend?

Tags: java, sql, database, jakarta-mail

For awhile I've been using the simple [Maildir](http://javamaildir.sourceforge.net) service provider to store emails for my app. However now I need to structure the data along with statistics in a database. Does anyone know if such a Store exists?

There doesn't seem to be one on the [Third party products](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/Third_Party.html) page with no luck.

To clarify my needs: I'm not writing an email client or server application. It is for a research project where we are analyzing user behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not used it, but Apache James looks like it will support a SQL Backend: http://james.apache.org/server/3/feature-persistence.html (Make sure you use version 3).

Amother option might be to use Apache James Mailets (These are like Servlets for mail) and have them write the statistics to a database when an action takes place on the mail server.

Comment: Hm. So if I understand the James site correctly, James is not simply a plugin for Javamail, but rather a separate email server stack? It seems somewhat overkill for my needs, as I do not need an entire email server, just a simple SQL Store to dump messages into for outside processing.

Comment: @Casey Correct James is a full fledge server. If you do not need real-time processing, then maybe a batch process that reads the folder and inserts the data you need into a database that you can do queries against might be the ticket ?

Comment: Yea, I expect that is what I will have to do. I sort of sold Javamail as being extensible (with this use case in mnid), so having to do this manually won't go over so well. I should've done my research beforehand. Ah well, thanks for the advice.